# Visual technique for fielding at point or cover

Tags: cricket, technique

When fielding at point or cover, should I focus my eyes on the batsman and try to pick the ball up when it enters my visual field as it's been hit; or should I look at the bowler as he runs up and keep my eyes on the ball while it is traveling down the pitch towards the batsman, turning my head keep track of the ball?

So far I have tried both and it seems to be easier to focus on the batsman, however if the ball is hit hard then I don't pick it up until it's almost past me.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I always watch the batsman whenever I'm fielding in line with or in front of the bat.  Trying to watch the ball places you at a disadvantage as you can take more cues about the shot from the way the batsman is setting themselves up.  If you try and watch the ball from the bowlers hand you can only react to whatever happens, if you watch the batsman you can anticipate the shot and give yourself a chance to set yourself for the sort of shot they look to be playing.